# Проблемы с переходами между фрагментами

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, rxandroid

Есть 3 фрагмента, первый (с которого запускается приложение отображается нормально), когда свайпаю, чтобы перейти на следующие фрагменты, то информация внутри них не отображается.Но вот что заметил, если я успеваю свайпнуть на следующий фрагмент до того, как на первом загрузится вся инфа(геолокация, данные с API, причем пока вся инфа грузится, то крутится loading, так вот пока он круится я успеваю свайпнуть, то все работает отлично, все фрагменты работают) на втором фрагменте есть RecycleVie. В logcat есть 2 ошибки :E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout и Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. возможно проблема в этом ?

MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;


private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
private LocationCallback locationCallback;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_view);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



    //Request permission
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {

                    if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                        buildLocationRequest();
                        buildLocationCallBack();

                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            return;
                        }
                        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MainActivity.this);
                        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                        Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Permission Denied", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                }
                }).check();
            }

private void buildLocationCallBack() {
    locationCallback = new LocationCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);

            Common.current_location = locationResult.getLastLocation();

            viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
            setupViewPager(viewPager);
            tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            //Log
            Log.d("Location", locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude()+"/"+locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude());

        }
    };

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(TodayWeatherFragment.getInstance(), "Today");
    adapter.addFragment(ForecastFragment.getInstance(),"5 days");
    adapter.addFragment(CityFragment.getInstance(), "Cities");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private void buildLocationRequest() {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
    locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10.0f);
}
```

}

```
Фрагмент с RecycleView
```

public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

```
CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable;
IOpenWeatherMap mService;

TextView txt_city_name, txt_geo_coord;
RecyclerView recycler_forecast;

static ForecastFragment instance;

public static ForecastFragment getInstance() {
    if(instance == null)
        instance = new ForecastFragment();
    return instance;
}

public ForecastFragment() {
    compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    mService = retrofit.create(IOpenWeatherMap.class);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forecast, container, false);

    txt_city_name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_city_name);
    txt_geo_coord= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_geo_coord);



    getForecastWeatherInformation();

    return itemView;

}



private void getForecastWeatherInformation() {
    compositeDisposable.add(mService.getForecastWeatherByLatLng(
            String.valueOf(Common.current_location.getLatitude()),
            String.valueOf(Common.current_location.getLongitude()),
            Common.APP_ID,
            "metric")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<WeatherForecastResult>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(WeatherForecastResult weatherForecastResult) throws Exception {
                    displayForecastWeather(weatherForecastResult);
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    Log.d("ERROR", ""+throwable.getMessage());
                }
            })


    );



}

private void displayForecastWeather(WeatherForecastResult weatherForecastResult) {
    txt_city_name.setText(new StringBuilder(weatherForecastResult.city.name));
    txt_geo_coord.setText(new StringBuilder(weatherForecastResult.city.coord.toString()));

    WeatherForecastAdapter adapter = new WeatherForecastAdapter(getContext(), weatherForecastResult);
    recycler_forecast.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

тут вы говорите что подписываться на getForecastWeatherByLatLng будете в IO пуле потоках, и при этом нигде не уточняете в каком потоке хотите получать результат, в результате в тех же потоках и получаете и обрабатываете, а при обработке с вашим UI взаимодействуете, что можно делать только из главного потока. Добавьте между строками:

```
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<WeatherForecastResult>() {
```

указание обрабатывать результат в главном потоке:

```
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<WeatherForecastResult>() {
```

И по идее всё должно заработать, других ошибок я на вскидку не вижу.